# PersistentVolumeClaim unknown in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

i try to deploy a container but unfortunately i have an error when i try to execute **kubectl apply -f *.yaml**

the error is :

> error validating data: ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[1]):
>   unknown field "persistentVolumeClaim" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container;

i dont understand why i get the error because i wrote  **claimName:** under **persistentVolumeClaim:** in my pd.yaml config :(

**Pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: karafpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: karaf
    image: xxx/karaf:ids-1.1.0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: karaf-conf-storage
      mountPath: /apps/karaf/etc
  - name: karaf-conf-storage
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: karaf-conf-claim
```

**PersistentVolumeClaimKaraf.yml**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: karaf-conf-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Mi
```

Deployment.yaml

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   name: karaf
   namespace: poc 
 spec:
   replicas: 1
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: karaf
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: karaf
         image: "xxx/karaf:ids-1.1.0"
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         ports:
         - containerPort: 6443
         - containerPort: 6100
         - containerPort: 6101
         resources: 
         volumeMounts:
         - mountPath: /apps/karaf/etc
           name: karaf-conf
       volumes:
       - name: karaf-conf
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: karaf-conf
```

Comment: It would really help to know which version of K8s you're running here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're seeing that error is due to you specifying a `persistentVolumeClaim` under your pod spec's container specifications. As you can see from the auto generated docs here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#container-v1-core

`persistentVolumeClaims` aren't supported at this level/API object, which is what's giving the error you're seeing.

You should modify the `pod.yml` to specify this as a volume instead.

e.g.:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: karafpod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: karaf
      image: xxx/karaf:ids-1.1.0
      volumeMounts:
      - name: karaf-conf-storage
        mountPath: /apps/karaf/etc
  volumes:
    - name: karaf-conf-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: karaf-conf-claim
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-pod), `persistentVolumeClaim` is a part of `.spec.volume` level, not `.spec.container` level of a `pod` object.

The correct `pod.yaml` is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: karafpod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: efgkaraf-conf-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: efgkaraf-conf-claim
  containers:
    - name: karaf
      image: docker-all.attanea.net/library/efgkaraf:ids-1.1.0
      volumeMounts:
      - name: efgkaraf-conf-storage
        mountPath: /apps/karaf/etc
```